# What is C# for C " FILE *f;"?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, c, file

I am a beginner in C#
I wonder how to write in C#  C's

```
static void example(const char *filename)
 {
FILE *f;
outbuf_size = 10000;
outbuf = malloc(outbuf_size);

f = fopen(filename, "wb");
     if (!f) {
       fprintf(stderr, "could not open %s\n", filename);
         exit(1); 
  }

fwrite(outbuf, 1, outbuf_size, f);
fclose(f);
}
```

Plase help.

BTW: Well I am trying to port FFMPEG api-example presented [here](http://www.squashedfrog.net/mythtv/devdocs/api-example_8c-source.html) using Tao.FFMpeg (Tao is .Net wrapper around C#.. old and with sintax exact as in FFMPEG itself) so could you please read that one and tell what I missed in my code sample...

My problem is - I understand how to port FFMpeg part and I just do not det how to port File IO part\function in the way good for .Net

Comment: Huh... you didn't assign the value of outbuf... (more specifically, the contents of the array are undefined)

Comment: See the MSDN [File class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since the sample code of the library you provided reads and writes binary files, I'd suggest System.IO.BinaryReader and [System.IO.BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx).

```
    static void example(string filename)
    {
        StreamReader sr;
        BinaryWriter bw;

        try
        {
            sr = new StreamReader(filename);

            bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("out.bin", FileMode.Create));

            bw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());

            bw.Flush();
            bw.Close();

            sr.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle the exception
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than writing all of the code for you, I'm going to direct you to [System.IO.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file_methods.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Your code sample is confusing. Either you mean to put something meaningful in the buffer and write it to the file, or you mean to read from the file into the buffer.

```
using System.IO;

byte[] bytesFromFile = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

byte[] someBytes = new byte[someLength];
// omitted: put some values into someBytes array
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, someBytes);
```

Comment: Well I am trying to port FFMPEG api-example presented here http://www.squashedfrog.net/mythtv/devdocs/api-example_8c-source.html using Tao.FFMpeg (Tao is .Net wrapper around C#.. old and with sintax exact as in FFMPEG itself) so could you please read that one and tell what I missed in my  code sample...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following namespace [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx). Specifically you will want to look at [System.IO.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) and also [System.IO.FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

See [FileStream.WriteByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.writebyte.aspx) help. There is an example.

Comment: English version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.writebyte.aspx

Comment: Sorry about that, sometimes I don't realise that I'm reading Spanish (my mother tongue) or English and this time I forgot to check :) Thanks jalf.